# index is getting called instead of show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to write an API using Ruby on Rails. In my controller class *index* method is getting called instead of *show*. Although I am passing parameters.

**tried these urls**

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/quatertodate/?invoiceStatus=PENDING
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/quatertodate/PENDING
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/quatertodate/:PENDING
```

In all of the above mentioned cases my *index* method is getting called instead of *show*.

**Respective Controller class**

```
module Api
module V1
    class QuatertodateController < ApplicationController

        def index   
            invoices = Invoice.select("*").where("invoiceDate >= ?", @@present_date-90)
            render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', messasge: 'LOADED QUATERLY INVOICES', data: invoices}, status: :ok
        end

        def show
            invoices1 = Invoice.select("*").where("invoiceStatus== ? AND invoiceDate >= ?", params[:invoiceStatus], @@present_date-90)
            #invoices1 = Invoice.find(params[:invoiceStatus])
      #invoices1=Invoice.select("*").where("invoiceStatus= ? and invoiceDate >= ?", params[:invoiceStatus], @@present_date-180)
            render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', messasge: 'LOADED QUATERLY INVOICES', data: invoices1}, status: :ok
        end

    end
end
```

end

**NOTE:** The commented portion *#invoices1* doesn't work either. Throws:

```
<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Invoice with 'customerId'=>
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "invoices", primary_key: "customerId", id: :integer, default: nil, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
t.string "customerNumber", limit: 12
t.string "customerType", limit: 5
t.string "invoiceType", limit: 5
t.decimal "invoiceAmt", precision: 65, scale: 30
t.string "invoiceStatus", limit: 12
t.datetime "invoiceDate"
```

**Possible *invoiceStatus* values:** BILLED or PENDING

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
namespace 'api' do
    namespace 'v1' do
        resources :invoices
        resources :monthtodate
        resources :quatertodate
        resources :yeartodate
    end
end
end
```

**rake routes**
[image: route]

**My objective:** To return invoices from last 90 days whose invoice status is PENDING.
I also have tried *update* method for *PATCH* request, instead of *show* but it is throwing this error

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'update' could not be found for Api:

Removing *index* method gives following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Invoice with 'customerId'=>"

What am I missing? Can anyone direct me towards right direction? I couldn't find any related docs either.

I'm new to Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to follow proper Rails and REST conventions you wouldn't use the `show` action for this. `show` is for showing one record, and is called with a URL of this format `api/v1/quartertodate/:id`, where `:id` is a dynamic variable for the `id` of the record you want to show. In the controller it is available as `params[:id]`.

`index` is for showing many records, even if it's not *all* of the records.

You can handle this with an `if...else` branch in the index action.

```
def index   
  @invoices = if params[:invoiceStatus].present?
    Invoice.where("invoiceStatus = ? AND invoiceDate >= ?", params[:invoiceStatus], ninety_days_past)
  else
    Invoice.where("invoiceDate >= ?", ninety_days_past)
  end

  render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', messasge: 'LOADED QUATERLY INVOICES', data: @invoices}, status: :ok
end

def show
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', messasge: 'LOADED INVOICE', data: @invoice}, status: :ok
end

private

def ninety_days_past
  Date.today - 90
end
```

Notes: You don't need `select('*')`, and you should be using an instance variable for `@invoices` because it will require less refactoring if you ever switch to a templating engine for your JSON API. Also, you don't need a global variable for today's date, just use the built in `Date` library and do `Date.today`. To find the date 90 days ago you can create a private method `ninety_days_past` so you're not duplicating the code. If you want this method in every controller just define that method directly in your `ApplicationController` *instead of* your `QuatertodateController`.

Comment: works like charm! can you please refer me any good (beginner friendly) docs/ talks?

Comment: @NiladriSekharBasu some of these might be useful. I also suggest you keep the Rails guides open in a tab on your browser and read those carefully https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/routing - https://www.sitepoint.com/an-in-depth-look-at-basic-rails-routing/ - http://rubylearning.com/blog/2014/01/29/routing-basics-ruby-on-rails-for-front-end-developers/ -
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html -
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

This url will reuest the index action:

```
 http://localhost:3000/api/v1/quatertodate?invoiceStatus=PENDING
```

Route next identifies the string **?invoiceStatus=PENDING** as id parameter. So it will request the show action.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/quatertodate/?invoiceStatus=PENDING
```

Comment: So what will be the correct solution to my problem? How can I correctly pass parameter to _show_?

Comment: Pass the variable to the generated path,  api_v1_ quatertodate_path(@quatertodate), It will generate route like http://localhost:3000/api/v1/quatertodate/1, The last 1 is id of the record.

Comment: will you kindly elaborate? Or give me an example or some references?

Comment: Ok, try my best. In your show action you get single record by   invoices1 = Invoice.select("*").where("invoiceStatus== ? AND invoiceDate >= ?", params[:invoiceStatus], @@present_date-90).first.   Then if you request the path: api_v1_ quatertodate_path(invoices1), It will call the show action.

Comment: that's not right, query strings such as `?invoiceStatus=PENDING` are not interpreted as the `id` parameter for the show action.